# How to add Skype link in LaTex on Overleaf?

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, links, hyperlink

I am trying to add my Skype link

```
\textit{Skype:} \href{skype:accountName?add}{accountName}
```

However, the text in the rendered latex document does not become clickable.

how can i fix this and add my Skype link ?

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example. If you add your code to a simple doc that loads `hyperref` it generates a clickable link. If it does not for you, then there is information missing.

Comment: `skype:`  is not a standard URI protocol, is there any PDF reader that supports it? Hyperref can add such a link but I do not know any pdf reader that could use it.

Comment: First, you have to load the package `hyperref`: `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Second, the link need to start with `https://` or another *protocol*: " Internet Protocols are a set of rules that governs the communication and exchange of data over the internet."
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-internet-protocols/

Comment: @Vebjorn `skype:` is such a protocol and most browsers allow add-ons that support such non standard schemes, but I'm not aware of pdf readers that do (unless reading the pdf in a web browser)

Comment: @daleif the provided example is minimal and complete ? please let me know what, in your opinion, is missing. I will gladly provide it if possible

Comment: @Vebjorn true, but i am not sure if a Skype URI is ever written with https

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have the same confusion , about `skype:` being clickable or not